# How to calculate percentage and store it in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and I want to add a new column with the percentage value:

```
df =

TIME_1   TIME_2
80       150
120      20
```

I want to get a new columt `TIME_1_PROC` that will store the percentage value of `TIME_1` from `TIME_1 + TIME_2`.

This is my code, but it triggers a warning:

```
df.TIME_1_PROC = (df.TIME_1*100/(df.TIME_1+df.TIME_2))
```

Warning:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: @Imo: The problem is that the column `TIME1_PROC` is not created for some reason. Is there any other approach to do the same task? This is just to try different approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This creates a new variable:

```
df['TIME1_PROC'] = (df.TIME_1 * 100 / (df.TIME_1 + df.TIME_2))

Out[27]: 
   TIME_1  TIME_2  TIME1_PROC
0      80     150   34.782609
1     120      20   85.714286
```

Comment: The problem is that it gives me the same values like TIME_1 and TIME_2... Cannot understand why this happens. Is there any alternative approach, e.g. using lambda? I am suing the last version of pandas.

Comment: Does this happen to you with the example DataFrame you provided?

Comment: No, it happens with my real dataset that is very big.

Comment: It works only when I store the values in a new variable: `bb = aa.apply(lambda row: (row['TIME_1']*100/(row['TIME_1']+row['TIME_2'])), axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Generally speaking...

Just a quick elaboration on @Imo's correct answer.  Most of the time you are better off creating and referring to columns like this:

```
df['x']
```

rather than this:

```
df.x
```

And when you are creating a new variable, you MUST use the first method.  But even for existing variables, the first way is considered better because you avoid potential errors if you happen to have a column called "index".  E.g. if you type `df.index`, will that return the index or the column named "index"?  Of course, we all use the attribute-style as a shortcut on occasion, so perhaps a more reasonable rule of thumb would be to only use the shortcut on the right hand side.

#### This particular example...

All that said, the behavior by pandas here does not seem ideal.  The warning message you got here is a common one in pandas and often ignorable (as it is here).  But what is unfortunate is that you didn't get an error message about attempting to access a non-existent column.  And furthermore consider the following:

```
df['TIME_1_PROC']     # KeyError: 'TIME_1_PROC'

df.TIME_1_PROC

0    34.782609
1    85.714286
dtype: float64
```

So your new column did get created, but as an *attribute* rather than a column.  To be more explicit here, usually when we use the attribute-style reference, it is interpreted by pandas as referring to a column.  But in this case it actually *is* an attibute (and that's not what you want).

Comment: This could be a comment on Imo's answer or should give a bit more of an example on how you should be setting to the new column such as `df['x'] = some_percentage_calc`.

Comment: @josh I agree it's a comment in spirit (and hence referred to it as an elaboration of Imo's answer), it was just way too long to fit.  Actually I was going to flag as a duplicate but I couldn't find another answer that really was as clear as I thought this should be about the difference between `df['x']` and 'df.x`.  There must be something in the official docs, but I couldn't find it

Comment: I just think being very explicit such as "In future do `df['x'] = perc` and not `df.x = perc`". The people looking for this will likely be at an early pandas use level so the explicitness helps. Maybe though I was too quick to comment :)

Comment: no worries, it's a fair point and it's generally better to do what I did as a comment (I just thought this was one of the rare times where an exception to the rule is justified)

Answer (score 0):

use pd.set_option('chained',None) to avoid such messages